# how to control mediaplayer volume

Tags: android

I created a simple application.
In my main activity class i use this to play a sound when a button is clicked

```
MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.button_sound); 

public void onClick(View arg0){
                buttonSound.start();
                             }
```

In my main activity class i have a service that start a background music

```
 Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
 startService(svc);
```

The problem is that I can't handle them (my background music and my button sound) with the volume buttons of my mobile.
If i decrease the volume of my mobile, my application volume doesn't change!
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **AudioManager** to control volumn of Media Player.

```
// Get the AudioManager
AudioManager audioManager =(AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Set the volume of played media to your choice.
audioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,10,0);
```

Also can use **setVolume (float leftVolume, float rightVolume)** for your media player as like as

```
buttonSound.setVolume(10,10);
```

Where
**Parameters**
**leftVolume**-->   left volume scalar
**rightVolume**-->  right volume scalar